# P:dialog is not working when the h:outputtext has the attribute escape=false

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In the below code when I am defining **escape=false** for the **h:outputtext** then the popup dialog window is not working

```
<h:dataTable value="#{template.htmlContentFiles}" var="regionVo">
    <p:column id="column1">
        <h:outputText var = "htmlContent" value="#{regionVo.fileContent}" escape="false" rendered="#{regionVo.editable}"/>
        <ck:editor id="ckEd" value="#{regionVo.fileContent}" rendered="#{not regionVo.editable}"/> 
        <div>
            <p:commandButton value="Show" type="button" onclick="PF('componentDlg').show();"/>
            <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="componentDlg" minHeight="40">
                <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
            </p:dialog>
        </div>
    </p:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Whereas the popup dialog shows up when I removed the escape=false.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the value(s) of `#{regionVo.fileContent}`? Might it contain special characters such as `<`? Any JS-console-output?

Comment: I am loading an HTML page into the filecontent. The part of the sample HTML file is:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
<title>Nurse Staffing</title>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,600,500,300,200,100' type='text/css'/>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="logo">Nurse Staffing</h1>
<form action="" method="post">

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce using JSF-2.1 and JSF 2.2.8 with primefaces 4.0. Works fine here. Any browser console output?